# Не конфигурируется Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, orm, hql

Весь день уже мучаюсь, не знаю что делать.

Есть обычный `HibernateUtil`:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {

        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println(sessionFactory);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Вот мой `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deepThoughtDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">228322</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.Facts"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.Tags"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.questions.QuestionContent"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.questions.QuestionImages"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.questions.Questions"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.posts.PostContent"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.posts.PostImage"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.posts.PostInsideImages"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.posts.PostsComments"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.posts.PostsInfo"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.user.LogInfo"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.user.UserImages"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.user.UserInfo"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.answer.AnswerImages"/>
      <mapping class="ru.projects.prog_ja.entity.answer.Answer"/>

      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Из xml видно, что здесь замаплены сущности, ну и вот проблема заключается в том, что у меня вылетает `NullPointerException` в классе `HibernateUtil`,в строке где происходит конфигурация.

Вот такого содержания:

```
Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@393881f0] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
авг 02, 2018 4:29:53 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
авг 02, 2018 4:29:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deepThoughtDB]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at TestMain.session(TestMain.java:20)
    at TestMain.run(TestMain.java:24)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3920)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at ru.projects.prog_ja.dao.Hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 3 more
```

Но, когда я убираю из `hibernate.cfg.xml` все маппинги, он нормально запускается. Помимо того он нормально запускается если я убираю все `@NamedQueries` над своими `Entity`, т.е. у меня на каждом `Entity` есть `NamedQuery` и если я убираю их всех до одного, то Hibernate работает, но если я оставляю хоть 1, то вылетает NPE, в чем может быть проблема?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

Пример одного из таких query, мб они просто не правильно написаны

```
select u from LogInfo l 
join fetch l.userInfo u 
join fetch u.userImage ui 
join fetch ui.imageS imgS
where l.mailH = :mail and l.passH = :pass
```

(При xml mapping-e Entity та же самая ситуация)

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2:**

Если убрать из запросов `join fetch`, то тогда всё начинает работать, только тогда как подгружать выбранные ссылки если иногда они нужны, а иногда нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо писать правильно

```
select u from LogInfo as l 
inner join l.userInfo as u 
inner join u.userImage as ui 
inner join ui.images
```

---

Как писать запросы и типы джойнов можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

> Соединение `fetch` позволяет инициализировать ассоциации или коллекции
>   значений вместе с их родительскими объектами с использованием одного
>   `select`. Это особенно полезно в случае коллекций. Оно эффективно
>   перекрывает `outer join` и ленивые объявления в файле маппинга
>   для ассоциаций и коллекций. Дополнительную информацию см. В разделе
>   [19.1 «fetch-стратегии»](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching).

---

Поскольку использование `fetch` в запросах *не меняет* результат выборки данных, а использует дополнительные запросы для инициализации объектов, то их можно убрать и использовать стратегию загрузки обектов, используемую в аннотациях маппинга.

Comment: Написал запрос в точности как у вас, но всё равно вылетел NPE

Comment: Поменял запрос, теперь все должно работать нормально.

Comment: работает только если убрать последнюю строку, мб из-за слишком большой вложенности он просто не может его сделать? Возможно где-то в конфигурации можно отрегулировать или так и должно быть.

Comment: Хотя в самой документации hibernate написано, что join fetch в глубину должен работать

Comment: Возможно это зависит от версии Hibernate.